# Which is bigger, $2^{2^{2^{1001}}}$ or $1000^{2^{2^{1000}}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As the question suggests, which number would be bigger? I attempted to use $2^{10}=1024>1000$ but got rather stumped, is there a neater way to approach this problem?

Comment: The first one is immensely bigger.

Comment: The message here is that the top of the stack matters a lot more than the bottom of the stack.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: show that the first one is equivalent to

$$2^{\left(2^{2^{1000}}\cdot 2^{2^{1000}}\right)}$$

And note

$$1000^{2^{2^{1000}}}< \left(2^{10}\right)^ {2^{2^{1000}}} = 2^{\left(10\cdot 2^{2^{1000}}\right)}$$

which is smaller than the first expression.

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt the solution is to take logarithms. Taking $\log_2$ of the two expressions gives $2^{2^{1001}}$ vs. $2^{2^{1000}} \log_2 1000$ which is already very clarifying; if we write $x = 2^{2^{1000}}$ then the first of these expressions is $x^2$ and the second is $x \log_2 1000$. Since $x$ is much larger than $\log_2 1000 < 10$ this is already enough to show that the first expression is much, much larger than the second (even after taking logarithms).

If that isn't enough, we can take $\log_2$ a second time. This gives $2^{1001}$ vs. $2^{1000} + \log_2 \log_2 1000$. If we now write $x = 2^{1000}$ then the first of these expressions is $2x$ while the second is $x + \log_2 \log_2 1000$, and $\log_2 \log_2 1000 < \log_2 10 < 4$ is quite small. So we see again that the first expression is much larger than the second (even after taking *two* logarithms!).

Repeatedly taking logarithms like this makes it clear that when analyzing the behavior of a tower of exponentials $x^{y^{z^{\dots}}}$, the exponents furthest up matter much, much, much more than the ones further down. In fact we could safely replace $1000$ by an enormously larger number here, any number less than $2^{2^{2^{1000}}}$.